# Jboss memory problem

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, memory-management

I am facing "Out Of Memory Error Exception" while running a web service application over jboss 4.2
how can I increase the memory of jboss ? and will this solve the problem ?

Answer (score 3):

You should first confirm if the memory usage is not abnormal. If it is not, it is probably a good idea to increase the memory allocation. JBoss default memory allocation is rather small at the default setting.

You want to confirm that the memory shortage is heap shortage (it could be permgen etc. if it is permgen, please refer to general OOME (OutOfMemoryError) questions). If you are using Java 1.6 you just need to read the exception message to determine this.

Once you confirm it is a heap shortage, it is advisable to confirm that there is no memory leak occurring before you go for a bigger heap size. To do this, you can attach a heap monitor like visualVM and monitor heap usage under stress (for more information see this: http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2009/how-to-fix-memory-leaks-in-java/).

Once you are done with this, and you are sure that you have a legitimate heap shortage, you can edit `run.conf` (Linux) or `run.bat` (Windows) to allocate more heap. You can search for JAVA_OPTS and change `-Xmx512m` to something like `-Xmx1024m`.

Comment: my current memory is "-Xms128m -Xmx512m" , so you recommend to change it to "Xms512m -Xmx1024m" right ? would this effect other system resources (Note jboss is current running over Linux server) ?

Comment: @roy: If you set Xmx to e.g. 1024m, it means that the java process will not use more than 1GB (plus a little bit more for stack/permgen etc.). So the question is, can you spare e.g. 512MB of extra RAM (because you were previously using 512MB for heap and now 1GB)? To determine this, you could use commands like `vmstat` and monitor if the server has enough RAM. To be specific, you could put the system under stress with the new config, and monitor the memory usage of the server. If there is no swapping occurring, you probably have enough RAM to spare.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the memory for JBoss, but make sure to find out *why* it uses more memory than expected to make sure the problem doesn't come back to bite you.

Set this in your shell before launching JBoss while experimenting:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx1024m"
```

Comment: I totally agree to this answer, but just one caveat: most JBoss start up scripts reset JAVA_OPTS, so setting the environment variable like this won't work in most cases.

Comment: my current memory is "-Xms128m -Xmx512m" , so you recommend to change it to "Xms512m -Xmx1024m" right ? would this effect other system resources (Note jboss is current running over Linux server) ?

Comment: This will let your Java process use memory if it needs it, other applications will then not have access to as much memory as they did before and therefore could be affected.